# How to pass values between xaml.cs to class1.cs page?

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, xaml, windows-phone-8

Here is the Main.xaml.cs page details,

```
private void Btn_Ok_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    String homeTeamId = TeamIdtxt.Text;

    this.DataContext = new MainViewModel();
}
```

and my class1.cs will be like as follows,

```
public MainViewModel()
{
    Players = new ObservableCollection<PlayersViewModel>();

    string url = "http://192.168.1.19/projects/t20lite/index.php/api/api/get_playersbyteam";
    var task = new HttpGetTask<PlayerList>(url, this.OnPostExecute);
    task.OnPreExecute = this.OnPreExecute;
    task.OnError = this.OnError;

    task.Execute();
}
```

how i have to pass the hometeam id value to mainviewmodel, In there i have to append it with url.

Comment: first, use binding to the view model (add a property in the viewmodel and bind TeamIdtxt to it). Second, you are missing a " sign at the end of the url.

Comment: you can pass it as constructor parameter, but why not use binding?

Answer (score 1):

As sugested in comments you can share data by several options:

Option 1: Using Data Binding  
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347(v=vs.110).aspx

Option 2: Define property in your ViewModel class to pass it. Add some method to handle get player request in your view-model. For example:

```
  public class MainViewModel
  {
     public string TeamID { get; set; }

     public MainViewModel()
     {
        Players = new ObservableCollection<PlayersViewModel>();
     }

     public void GetPlayer()
     {
        string url = "http://192.168.1.19/projects/t20lite/index.php/api/api/get_playersbyteam;"
        // Do something with url and tour TeamID
        var task = new HttpGetTask<PlayerList>(url, this.OnPostExecute);
        task.OnPreExecute = this.OnPreExecute;
        task.OnError = this.OnError;

        task.Execute();
     }   
  }
```

And you need to create your ViewModel once. So I suggest you to create your ViewModel in constructor of your View instead of button-click handler.

```
  public class MainView
  {
     public MainView()
     {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.ViewModel = new MainViewModel();
     }

     public MainViewModel ViewModel
     {
        get { return this.DataContext as MainViewModel; }
        set { this.DataContext = value; }
     }

     private void TeadIdText_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
     {
         this.ViewModel.TeamID = TeamIdtxt.Text;        
     }

     private void Btn_Ok_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
     {         
         this.ViewModel.GetPlayer();   
     }         
  }
```

Comment: Consider i got my teamid as 23 but it's dynamic , i have to append it along with url. hear you suggests me teamid in get and set, but how i will define it in mainviewModel() method. I'm a newbie will you brief it.

Comment: Expand my answer, added more details.